# CONDA: [Errno 48] Address already in use

Tags: conda, chatbot, miniconda, rasa-nlu, rasa-x

I'm trying to use Rasa in a miniconda3 environment to create a chatbot.
My venv is called `rasa_chat`. After calling `rasa init` I was successfully able to create and train a chatbot model. But when I try to talk to the trained assistant through terminal using `rasa shell` I get this error message:

[image]

I'm assuming that this error means there's another process running in the location required to run rasa shell. But when I ran `ps -fA | grep python` inside my `rasa_bot` venv I didn't see any process running that would obstruct the call.

Here is the list of processes currently running:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Or is there something I'm missing? I'm super new to using rasa and conda so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Find:

```
sudo lsof -i :5005
```

Kill:

```
kill -9 <PID>
```